# OpenShift egress router not working

Tags: openshift, router, sdn

i configured an egress router like described here:
https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.3/admin_guide/managing_pods.html#admin-guide-controlling-egress-traffic

But it does not work.
In my understanding, the options will be resolved like this:

- name: EGRESS_SOURCE     <-- This is the network where the nodes live (in my case the vm where the Containers are running on)
    value: 192.168.12.99
- name: EGRESS_GATEWAY <-- The gateway over which the destination ip address is routable.
    value: 192.168.12.1
- name: EGRESS_DESTINATION <--- The destination ip of the application i want to reach. In my case its a mongoDB living in a classical VM.

  value: 203.0.113.25

Am i right or do i miss something ?

How would i be able to reach the target ?

Do i need to address the source ip to access the MongoDB or do i simply address the IP of my MongoDB an the traffic gets nat'd the way over my egress router (This is how i understood the traffic flow will be btw.) ?

How can i troubleshoot this kind of problem ?

Best Regards,
Marcus

Comment: Ok, it worked by now. I created a service and adressed the ip of this service to reach my target.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it worked by now. I created a service and adressed the ip of this service to reach my destination. 
The alternative way is to address the ip of the container.

So from inside the container to reach your original destination don't use the original ip, rather use the egress pod ip or preferred use the ip of the created service.

!!Attention: The destination ip must be outside of the host/node ip range otherwise it would not work. It seems that, if you use a destination ip from your host/node range, the standard gw will get the request and i think it will discard it. !!

And i would suggest to use the egress router image from redhat, instead the origin, which is stated in the official document from redhat...

```
image: registry.access.redhat.com/openshift3/ose-egress-router
```